# ¿Como modificar la ruta de dominio de una carpeta en cpanel?

Tags: archivo, hosting, dominio

Necesito poder cambiar la carpeta que da referencia la ruta del dominio en cpanel,cree una carpeta llamado prueba en public_html para que ese dominio de referencia a la carpeta public_html en vez de otra carpeta en el cual da referencia pero me aparece el siguiente error al intentar cambiar la ruta :

[image: Error]

Ejemplo para actualizar :

[image: Actualizar]